# assign all while results to a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select statement. It selects all my tags from a database. Each tag is an entry so when the query gets results they come out as `tag1tag2tag3` if echoed within the while statement. When I echo the results outside the while statement I get tag3. I would like to get tag1,tag2,tag3 as a result. What is the best way to approach this?

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tags WHERE vid_id=?";
$gettags = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$gettags->execute(array($vid_id));
while ($row=$gettags->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$tags=$row['name'];
}
echo $tags; //produces tag3 if entries are tag1tag2tag3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning `$tags` each iteration. So it only outputs the last tag returned.

It's common to build an array in this case and then use a function like [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) for the output.

```
$tags = array()
while ($row=$gettags->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $tags[] = $row['name'];
}
echo implode(', ', $tags);
```

**Note:** Depending on the context and your DB platform, you may be able to do this entirely at the database level with something like `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: Interesting about Group_concat. Thanks again Jason.

Comment: No problem. Like I said, it be applicable if you are only using tags for display. Nonetheless, having all tags in an array could be helpful in other areas of your code.

Answer (score 4):

```
$tags = array()
while ($row = ...) {
   $tags[] = $row['name'];
}
echo implode($tags);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tags WHERE vid_id=?";
$gettags = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$gettags->execute(array($vid_id));
$tags = '';
while ($row=$gettags->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $tags .= $row['name']; //concatenate the strings
}
echo $tags; //produces tag1tag2tag3
```

Comment: Hey Neal thanks. What is the difference from your answer to an array solution. Is there an efficiency or best coding practice difference?

Comment: @Scarface i was just doing what was posted in ur OP. to make a string. if you want an array use `$tags = array()` and `$tags[] = $row['name']`

Answer (score 2):

```
$tags = array();
$i = 0;


while ($row=$gettags->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $tags[$i]=$row['name'];
    $i++;
}

echo $tags;
```

Comment: Hey mrK, why bother with the $i?

Comment: @Scarface Not necessary, just a coding preference on my part.  I usually like to keep track of how many records I had for later use.

Comment: to track how many records in array. Use count($array); it will return counting of array elements.